# why doesn't select2 multiselect work using cdn?

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I'm using this code

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#state').select2({
        placeholder: "Select a state",
        allowClear: true
        });
    });
</head>
```

And in body:

```
        <div>
            <select id="state" name="state" multiple>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="MY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

But still it doesn't look as needed
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div>
    <select id="state" name="state" multiple>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="MY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

   <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery.noConflict();
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#state').select2({
            placeholder: "Select a state",
            allowClear: true
          });
      });
    </script>

</div>
```

You are missing `</script>` tag

Comment: Thank you so much, I corrected it, but I don't get the result as after running that snippet here. It seems that <script type="text/javascript"> doesn't work

Comment: I still didn't get it in my program, it works only here